# Flask Config file is not working

Tags: python, flask, configuration-files

From the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/), I was trying to implement config in my project. But It doesn't seems to be working as expected. I might be wrong. but I did not understand what I am missing.

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    TIMEOUT_COUNT=60
    DBCONFIG ={
      'DBNAME' : 'dbname',
      'DBUSER' : 'laxmikant',
      'DBPASSWORD' : '*******',
      'DBHOST' : 'localhost'
    }

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SERVER_NAME = 'PRODUCTION'
    dbcredentials = {'DBUSER' : 'produser', 'DBPASSWORD':'******'}
    Config.DBCONFIG.update(dbcredentials)

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    SERVER_NAME = 'DEVELOPMENT'
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True
    dbcredentials = {'DBUSER' : 'devuser', 'DBPASSWORD':'******'}
    Config.DBCONFIG.update(dbcredentials)
```

Before running `python run.py` I set `APP_SETTINGS` as per the enviornment:

```
export APP_SETTINGS="config.ProductionConfig" #- on production server
export APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig" #- on dev server
```

I read the config file and printed DBCONFIG for both the server:

```
   environment = os.environ['APP_SETTINGS']
   app.config.from_object(environment)
   print '''[{}]  INFO {}'''.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME'], app.config['DBCONFIG'])
```

Following is the actual output for production server:

```
$ export APP_SETTINGS="config.ProductionConfig"
laxmikant:~/workspace/project-xyz$ python run.py 
[PRODUCTION]  INFO {'DBPASSWORD': '******', 'DBUSER': 'devuser', 'DBHOST': 'localhost', 'DBNAME': 'dbname'}
[02-10 2016 22:39:33]  INFO - * Running on http://0.0.0.0:3004/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And for DEV Server

```
$ export APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"
laxmikant:~/workspace/project-xyz$ python run.py 
[DEVELOPMENT]  INFO {'DBPASSWORD': '******', 'DBUSER': 'devuser', 'DBHOST': 'localhost', 'DBNAME': 'dbname'}
[02-10 2016 22:41:40]  INFO - * Running on http://0.0.0.0:3004/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The query is, why `development` and production `config` is giving same `DBCONFIG` info?

** NOTE** - I won't be using `python run.py` for production but here I just have to test the config. so please ignore `python run.py`

Comment: @Hussain -sorry that was the typo!

Comment: @Hussain - Getting error  `name 'DBCONFIG' is not defined`

Comment: Oh. Okay. I can't think of any reason why this is happening. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update the same parent class's dictionary in subclasses. Try to copy and update it:

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    dbcredentials = {'DBUSER' : 'produser', 'DBPASSWORD':'******'}
    DBCONFIG = Config.DBCONFIG.copy()
    DBCONFIG.update(dbcredentials)

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    dbcredentials = {'DBUSER' : 'devuser', 'DBPASSWORD':'******'}
    DBCONFIG = Config.DBCONFIG.copy()
    DBCONFIG.update(dbcredentials)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the mistake!